# .htaccess: forward to url but keep current url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to forward an url1 (www.currentdomain.com/folder/) to another url2 (www.otherdomain.com). But i don't want to change the url in the addressbar. (I want it to show www.currentdomain.com/folder/

I've tried a couple of things and got this to do a forward. It changes url1 to url2 tough:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/url1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL2` is not very descriptive. BUT, if URL2 is **not** local and like `anotherdomain.com` and not a URI, it will do a redirect. You can't do an internal redirect with another domain.

You will have to use `mod_proxy` and the `[P]` flag on your rewriterule.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html

Comment: URL is indeed not local. I'll adapt the question